# Why is vercel deployment giving me this error: Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member? [next13]

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, vercel

Im trying to use vercel to deploy my first next13 project. I have ran next build locally and the project builds fine but when I push my branch to trigger a deployment, the build fails with `Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member` Ive tried adding making a custom build script that runs `npx prisma generate && next build`. That did not fix the issue. Has anyone else ran into this issue or have anything I could try? thanks!

here is part of my prisma schema and I have doubled checked that the missing model is in the schema

````
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output = "../node_modules/.prisma/client"
}```
````

Comment: Did you come up with a solution with this ?
I'm having the same issue when deploying on vercel